# How to assert inputed date Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, date, webdriver, assert

I want to send some date in date field and then I need to check it is correct.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="form-control"]').send_keys("19. 01. 2020")

element3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="form-control"]').get_attribute("value")

assert element3.strip() == "19. 01. 2020"
```

Everytime there is Assert error. I tried send the string without spaces etc...

Comment: Have you tried to see what value `element3` has?

Comment: And how can i see it?

Comment: In debug mode in your IDE

Comment: Yes, its 19. 1. 2020

Comment: Its same but it fails.

Comment: You did not notice the absence of 0 in the received date

Comment: Isn't there problem with calendar itself, because I am sending it into calendar field when is option for pick date too...

Comment: Absence of 0 sign?

Comment: `element3 = 19. 1. 2020` right? but you are trying to compare with this: `19. 01. 2020`

Comment: Ok I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Try to fix by following: `assert element3.strip() == "19. 1. 2020"`